# Localised formatting for an input tag helper (Date)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like a way to display my ViewModel property (date) with the format yyyy-MM-dd - using taghelpers.

Note: I already know how to show this result via the @Html.DisplayFor property but it seems unproductive to have to jump between tag helpers and html helpers depending on what property is shown.

```
[Display(Name = "Date purchased")]     
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
```

None of the examples below work:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <input asp-for="PurchaseDate" type="date" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <input asp-for="PurchaseDate" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <input asp-for="PurchaseDate" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
</div>
```

Comment: The displayed date format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's browser. You can visit this link to refer more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date. And if you inspect the input element, you see, the value following format: yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have also found the solution by experimenting more:
Explicitly changing the type to "text" will display my annotated format.